# After making function call in the programme ,control is jumping into the unspecified memory location

Tags: c, gps, arm, embedded

i am developing a gps code which takes the raw data from the gps and decodes the data and saves it into the  respected variables(arrays).The problem  is whenever i make the function call,it is executing the function statements upto the end of the function ie., "}" ,and after that the control is going into some unspecified memory locations insted of handover the control to main function.
why it is happening? without using the microcontroller, the code is working fine in compiler,why?Is there any steps i need to take care for microcontroller registers?

```
void gps_Gpgga_data_pro_funct(void)
{
 int            loop1 , loop2  , loop3 ;

 unsigned char  commapos = 0;           //to hold the comma position
 unsigned char  tempbuff[100];       //temparary buffer

str_cpy(tempbuff,aa_GPS_GPGGA_RxBuffer); //received data taking into tempbuff

if(tempbuff[3] == 'G' && tempbuff[4] == 'G' && tempbuff[5] == 'A')
    {
         loop1 = 0;
         loop2 = 7;
          while(tempbuff[loop2] != COMMA)                //getting the time
          {
           gga_time[loop1] = tempbuff[loop2];
           loop1 ++;
           loop2 ++;
          }
                                //storing the comma position in a variable.
          gga_time[loop1] = '\0';           //GPGGA time
          commapos = loop2 ; 
          loop1 = 0;
          loop2 = 0;
          loop2 =  commapos + 1;                //setting the position for latitude
          while(tempbuff[loop2] != COMMA)        //receiving the latitude value
          {
           gga_lat[loop1] = tempbuff[loop2] ;
           loop2 ++;
           loop1 ++;
          }
          commapos = loop2;                      //saving the commaposition
          gga_lat[loop1] = '\0';            //GPGGA latitude

          loop1 = 0;
          loop2 = 0;
         loop2 = commapos + 3;

          while(tempbuff[loop2] != COMMA)            // receiving the longitude value
          {
           gga_long[loop1] = tempbuff[loop2] ;
           loop1 ++;
           loop2 ++;
          }
          commapos = loop2 ;
          gga_long[loop1] = '\0';               //GPGGA longitude

    }
else
    {
        /*do nothing*/
    }
}
```

Comment: What will happen when there are not enough `COMMA`s in the input, or if the input is longer than 99 bytes?

Comment: this is my raw data from the gps continuosly getting. $GPGGA,060723.00,1234.5678,N,1234.5678,E,,,M,,M,,*81.from this function based on the comma position i'm storing the values into the arrays.

Comment: DO NOT rely on this input! Always be prepared to have invalid chars in the input!

Comment: Aside: you should be picking up the `N` and the `E` too, in case they say `S` and `W`. Perhaps your app doesn't expect that, but your assumptions generally make for weak code.

Comment: @Olaf last 2 bytes, after *, are checksum. I hope OP check it to validate RX buffer. If this is granted function can avoid to check integrity twice.

Comment: @LPs: Yes, but to me it looks like buffer overflow in the first place. Further improvements need to be done, but it would be sufficient to verify the checksum at the end. And: not sure what kind of cheksum this is (suppose it is not a proper CRC?), but I would check validity of each char anyway using a proper lightweight scanner/parser. This asumes corruption to be unlikely, otherwise I would first verify the checksum.

Comment: @Olaf Checksum is a simple XOR of bytes. I guess/hope OP is validating RX chars on the RX reciver function/interrupt.

Comment: @LPs: I had expected this, taking the age of NEMA into account. So, one really should not just use this to validate the input, but also use the formatting.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess you are using [NMEA 0183](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NMEA_0183) standard protocol for GPS.

Messages are `<CR> <LF>` terminated and not NULL terminated.

Then check if your is not using string function to do the work.

I mean that the str_cpy has to look like below:

```
str_cpy(char *tempbuff, char *aa_GPS_GPGGA_RxBuffer, uint8_t bufferlength)
{
   for (int i=0; i<bufferLength; i++)
   {
      *(tempbuff+i) = *(aa_GPS_GPGGA_RxBuffer+i);
   }
}
```

Another problem I think your application could have is how `aa_GPS_GPGGA_RxBuffer` is filled. This because of you are coping the RXmessage in a temp buffer.
I guess that the reason that drive you to copy received message to a tempbuffer is  that the RX buffer has to be refilled by another task/interrupt.

In that case, are use sure that the RX buffer cannot be overwritted during your copy to tempbuffer?

Anyway you have always to check integriti of your message before to do this: I hope you did the checksum of received messages before to validate the RX buffer.

Last little thing, this code doesn't make sense:

```
commapos = loop2 ; 
loop1 = 0;
loop2 = 0;
loop2 =  commapos + 1;
```

you can change it to:

```
loop1 = 0;
loop2++;
```

**EDIT:**

As repored by  @Weather Vane: switching between `unsigned char` and `int` variables is never a good idea.

Comment: Re your last remark about `commapos`, switching between `unsigned char` and `int` variables will sooner or later lead to tears.

Comment: changes helped me a lot.

Answer (score 2):

This sounds like a classic buffer overflow overwriting the return address. Check tempbuff. `str_cpy()` might be a good start (if it is like `strcpy()`, it will overflow the buffer is the source is not `NUL`-terminated). You might pass the buffer size to it to prevent overflow under all circumstances (even of the source is malformed).

The remaining code is also pretty "optimistic", as it will exhibit **undefined behaviour** (UB) if the input is corrupted. Without proper range-checking, I would not accept such code! Keep in mind that all external (not self-generated) data may be corrupted. And according to murphy's law it *will*.

Also, It is not clear why you copy the data first to the buffer. It would be much faster and easier to parse it directly from the input buffer.

Comment: when i'm debugging the code it is successfully executing the statements untill the "}" of the function ,after that it is going into the unspecified memory locations.With the help of debug option i observed that the assembly code ,there the control is jumping into the unspecified memory insted of giving the control to calling function.

Comment: If it does not return to the caller, there is no use in further debugging. This is a clear sign the return address has become corrupted, resulting in UB. So, you should follow my answer, as that is exactly what would happen on buffer overflow (unless your CPU has an ascending stack - quite unlikely).

Comment: @LPs answer addresses that, if `str_cpy` expects a `'\0'` terminator, it skips the `CR/LF` and overflows the local buffer when it has found a `'\0'` somewhere.

Comment: @WeatherVane: yes, that's what I meant by `NUL`-terminated. Just don't refer to NEMA explicitly. Question is which format the input actually has and if it is properly terminated or not. The receiver thread/interrupt may very well do this and even veryfy the checksum (I might have preferred that actually, depending on tolerable interrupt behaviour).

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like corruption to me. Most likely stack overflow or stack corruption. I'd halt in the debugger at different points in the code and take a look at the link register that has been pushed onto the stack and see if it changes at any point during execution. It could be getting corrupted from an interrupt or other function as well. This will require understanding of the ARM/C calling convention, so you may have to do some research.

Comment: Corruption from an interrupt is much less likely than from malformed input data (corruption during reception e.g. or unexpected input). One should always check external input at least. Finding corruption from an interrupt is actually a pain in the a** to find.

Answer (score 0):

As Andrew said, it sounds like stack corruption. One possibility is that you are writing beyond the end of tmpbuff, and it looks to me as if that's in the str_cpy. You could try using strncpy instead, or (massively) increasing the tmpbuff size; if that sorts the problem then the thing to fix is that the rx buffer is not giving you a string of length at most 99, as your code assumes.